# Fractional and Exterior Calculus

Tags: soft-question

I am interested in fractional calculus and was wondering is there an equivalent/analagous fractional exterior calculus or fractional theory of differential forms? If so can someone point me out to some good books on it or papers?

Comment: Typing "fractional differential forms" immediately yields plenty results of a paper on it. I would be shocked if any books (or even large papers) have been written on this subject - fractional differentiation is already fairly niche. As someone who has studied the geometry of complex roots under fractional differentiation, I have found firsthand that the literature is scare and sporadic at times, if it even exists.

Comment: Thank you I didn't even think of that I was trying Fractional Exterior Calculus the whole time.

Comment: Searching for “fractional exterior calculus” brought up https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-14003-7_12.